# Google Cloud Platform - App Engine - can't stop and delete a version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I wonder is it possible to stop and remove an app's version? I use App Engine.
I tried many times but no success. Also I tried to do it if the app is inactive, still can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/delete-tutorial-resources#deleting_app_versions) you can stop an App Engine version only if your app has manual or basic scaling. Also, you cannot delete a version that is sharing traffic.

Meaning, if you only have one version in the default App Engine service, the only way you can delete the version of your App Engine app is by deleting your project.

There's currently a public Feature Request open to allow a full deletion of an App Engine app in a project which you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35874988).

In any way, if you wish to, you can always disable the App Engine app completely as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/?csw=1#disabling_an_application).

Comment: Thanks Maxim, looks like I'll have to completely remove the App Engine app. Also, please, can you take a look at the other my topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554449/google-cloud-platform-one-test-app-90-month-cost-why?