# Google Cloud Platform - one test app - $90/month cost - why?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a small test Angular static html app(10MB) deployed via Firebase Console and thought it is completely free. It's not a Node.js app.
When I take a look a the billing panel a month later I sow these nice lines:

Compute Engine N1 Predefined Instance Core running in Americas: 2159.983 Hours - $68.28.

Compute Engine N1 Predefined Instance Ram running in Americas: 8099.938 Gibibyte-hours - $34.32

[image]

GCP, I love you much!!!

Tell me guys, how this can be? I almost didn't use this app, just opened it 10 - 15 times during a month.

Sorry but I completely can't see the benefits of GCP. I can have Apache hosting in my country just for $3 - $5 per a MONTH but not per a day and no pain at all.

Comment: There is no question and no code. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: There is no question and no code - I got it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

> Tell me guys, how this can be? I almost didn't use this app, just opened it 10 - 15 times during a month.

You pay not for running app but for resources. And you where utilizing 3 vCPUs and 12 GB RAM during full month.

P. S. I strongly recommend to read description and price list **before** starting instances.

Comment: read description and price list before starting instances - thanks, I will!

Comment: Just one point - I have two more static apps deployed at Google Firestore. I've been using them almost one year. They don't use 3 vCPUs and 12 GB RAM. So the question: who has turned on Compute Engine service for my Firebase app???

Comment: Sorry, for wasting your time! I found that I created the VM instances by MYSELF several months ago while exploring the GCP! Thanks! ))) You saved my life...and money as well.

Comment: Glad that I could help. And yes GCP billing statements are somewhat confusing.